# nvidia-smi does not work, it keeps showing static but wrong information

Tags: python, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-smi

On my machine Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS， the command "nvidia-smi" suddenly does not work, it keeps showing static historical information.

1. Some programs using GPU have stopped, but when running "nvidia-smi", we can still see the GPU usage. However, when we found the program through PID, it did have been killed.
2. I run a new program using GPU. But when I ran the command "nvidia-smi", no GPU usage of the new program was shown.

Following is the picture when I run "nvidia-smi" for the first time [nvidia-smi result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhgEI.png)

Then the second time
[nvidia-smi result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQGuR.png)

They are the same, and nvidia-smi does not update any new information.

When I run "watch -n 1 nvidia-smi" to dynamically see the GPU usage, it remains static and displays the wrong GPU usage.

Further, when I ran the command "nvidia-smi -h", help information was not shown, It kept showing the static historical information shown in the above figures.